# Use FInd/Replace to re-order attributes in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, attributes

Across many hundreds of pages in an old webforms app, there are GridViews declared in HTML as

```
<asp:GridView GridLines="None" ..... >
```

where *every* GridView tag starts with `<asp:GridView GridLines="None"`

This is a shot in the dark, but I'm wondering if the GridLines property can be moved to the end of the tag using RegEx in a Search & Replace? For example,

```
<asp:GridView GridLines="None" .....>
```

would become

```
<asp:GridView ..... GridLines="None">
```

`.....` represents the many other attributes that can exist, which aren't declared in any particular order.

### Update

Some GridView controls use Resource file data to allow multi-lingual output.  This tag gets corrupted, so can RegEx account for that?

```
<asp:GridView GridLines="None" ..... EmptyDataText="<%$ Resources: Reports, NoResultsFound %>" .....>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. To address the issue of non-serialzed `>` and `<`, you can use

```
  GridLines="None"([^<>]*(?>(?>(?'open'<)[^<>]*)+(?>(?'-open'>)[^<>]*)+)+(?(open)(?!)))
```

Replacement:

```
 $1 GridLines="None"
```

See [demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=GridLines%3d%22None%22(%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*(%3f%3e(%3f%3e(%3f%27open%27%3c)%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*)%2b(%3f%3e(%3f%27-open%27%3e)%5b%5e%3c%3e%5d*)%2b)%2b(%3f(open)(%3f!)))&i=%3casp%3aGridView+GridLines%3d%22None%22+.....+EmptyDataText%3d%22%3c%25%24+Resources%3a+Reports%2c+NoResultsFound+%25%3e%22+.....%3e&r=%241+GridLines%3d%22None%22) (go to `Context` tab at the bottom to see the replacement results).

Comment: Sorry there's a problem.  I should have seen this but didn't.  I've updated the question and would appreciate further input please if possible

Comment: Can you please check? I added a .NET-style regex to match nested angle brackets. I hope you run this check on the server side in ASP, so that we can leverage .NET regex. On client side, with JS-style regex, we'd need a different one :(